# What exactly is #define useful for?

Tags: c++, constants

Now, bear with me, I'm new to [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). While following an online tutorial for [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), it mentioned that all `#define` is used for is to define a constant, like this.

```
#define RANDOM_CONSTANT 288
```

What I'm confused about is, why can't it just be done by creating a variable like this?

```
int RANDOM_CONSTANT = 288;
```

Does `#define` have any other applicable uses other than defining constants?

Comment: It has _many_ useful purposes, of which constants is not one of them.  What tutorial are you using?

Comment: @MooingDuck [Tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/index.htm)

Comment: Oh, the tutorial says that you _can_ use `define` for constants to improve readability.  Later on down the page, it goes into other uses as well.  Ok, that's fine.

Comment: Today it is better to use `int const RANDOM_CONSTANT = 288;`. In early versions of C that wasn't possible and `#define` was the best option. C++ chose (probably for practical reasons) to use the same preprocessor as C.

Comment: @MooingDuck I guess I speed-read to quickly.

Comment: You'd want `const int RANDOM_CONSTANT = 288;` to make the name a constant expression. But as inetknght's answer points out, that doesn't let you use it in a `#if` expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#define` is used to define some of the text substitutions performed by the preprocessor.  If you write

```
#define foo 417
```

and then refer to `foo` in your program, all instances of the identifier `foo` will be turned into the number `417`.  (But `foo4` will remain as `foo4`, for instance.)

```
#define twice(x) x,x
```

then an occurrence of `twice(417)` in your program will turn into `417,417`.

If I were you, I wouldn't worry about it too much at this stage.

Answer (score 2):

`#define` allows you to change the environment before compile time. So for example, you can use `#if RANDOM_CONSTANT` will allow you to modify *what code gets compiled*.

This is highly useful so that you can conditionally compile, for example, debugging features based on whether or not certain things were `#define`d or not.

Answer (score 2):

`#define` defines MACROs, not constants. `#define`, for example, may have certain parameters:

```
#define A(i) printf("%d", i)
```

Comment: Consider `#define LOG(message) WriteToLog(__FILE__, __LINE__, message)`  That saves a LOT of typing.

Comment: @MooingDuck Yes, as C++ improves #define becomes less important, but it's still not dead.  There are things that can be done using #define that are "impossible" otherwise.   (and I think your response applies to user3879237's answer, not to my comment)

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be two issues to address here:

1. What is `#define` useful for?
2. Why use constants instead of variables?

The answers to which are:

1. `#define` can do more complicated things then just replace a number with a name. It can actually take parameters. For example: `#define getmax(a,b) a>b?a:b` does not merely replace a number with a name.
2. Two parts: First, constants cannot be edited by the program (hence the name ;) ) so this in a way is a sort of safe guard. Second, it is precompiled not a variable so it takes no storage space and doesn't need to be looked up making it more efficient.

Comment: I don't think he's actually asking the second one, only the first question

Comment: @MooingDuck He asked "What I'm confused about is, why can't it just be done by creating a variable like this?" So he wants to see why constants have an advantage other variables in this usage.

Comment: Hmm, I interpreted it as him saying "when should I use a define as opposed to a _constant_ like this", but rereading, your interpretation is also possible.

Comment: You should use parenthesis in your macro definitions because just `a>b?a:b` won't work well in many situations.